# How to simulate pinch when controlling phone with "Your Phone" app?

Tags: windows-10, android, your-phone

I've been using the Window 10 "Your Phone" app a lot recently. One of the issues I've encountered is that I can't seem to zoom in most games that require it.  Things I've tried:

- Scroll Wheel (obviously)
- Middle-Click + drag (This opens Google Assistant)
- Right-Click + Drag (This closes the app)

Is there a way to simulate a pinch or zoom using the Your Phone app?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/whats-new-apps) (see section "10/3/2019") it should be supported on at least some devices.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Robert's comment, [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/apps/your-phone#phone-screen-on-more-devices) is the updated link (original link is dead).

It says:

> ...You can try out multi-touch gestures such as pinch to zoom, rotate, or swipe from your PC’s **touchscreen** while using Phone screen.

[Emphasis mine]

So, pinching should work while using Your Phone's `Open phone screen`, but only if your PC has a touchscreen as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung S22, what I have found to work is setting up the accesibility shortcuts menu beforehand. Then opening the screen to my phone using Link To Windows, within that accessibility menu there is a "Pinch" that you can use with your mouse. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).